# Why the threads are not reused in the Thread Pool?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, threadpool

I am trying to implement the thread pool model in C, but I have a problem with the threads themselves. I create 10 pthreads and I have a queue that contains the packets they need to process, but the problem is that when I have, for example, 100 packets threads still process only the first 10 of them. So, I guess they just stop working after the first use. How can I make threads be reused after they finished processing the previous packet?

Here is the creation of the threads:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        pthread_create(&t[i],NULL,func,args);
    }
```

Then, when I receive a new packet to work with I am enqueueing it into the work queue:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&q_mux);
enqueue(queue,p);
pthread_cond_broadcast(&qcond);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&q_mux);
```

And finally, I am taking the first packet in the queue, and dequeuing it:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&q_mux);
while(isempty(queue)){  
        pthread_cond_wait(&queue_cond,&q_mux);
}
p=queue->head->p;
dequeue(queue);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&q_mux);
process(p);
```

Comment: Yes, you are asking why some code doesn't work, but you haven't shown any code. See [mcve].

Comment: @qwerty post just enough code that somebody can copy and paste the code into a text editor and compile it and run it to see the problem happen for themselves.

Comment: Well, 'while(1) processQueueItem();' seems like a good plan.

Answer (score 2):

Hypothesis: there is not a *"until queue empty loop*" around the thread processing logic, and the threads are terminating normally after waiting for and processing a single item.

This matches the behavior of only processing 10 items, 1 item for each of the 10 threads created. `pthread_create` simply starts a new thread and threads do not automatically restart once their processing is complete.

Consider:

```
 // Loop until all items processed..
 while (!shutdown) {
     // take first packet and dequeue.. 99 packets of bits in the queue..
     pthread_mutex_lock(&q_mux);
     // ..
 }
```

Of course, have to work in what `shutdown` means and use it in conjunction with `(not) isempty` checking as to avoid deadlocks on a queue that is empty.

One way to deal with such is to queue up an "is finished" item after all of the items to be processed. When a thread encounters this item they will terminate by returning from the main loop inside each thread.

```
// Inside a thread, loop indefinitely and consume from the
// queue until encountering an item that indicates processing
// should stop.
while (true) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&q_mux);
    while (!shutdown & isempty(queue)) {  
        pthread_cond_wait(&queue_cond,&q_mux);
    }
    p=queue->head->p;
    if (p->is_finished) {
        // Run into 101'th item with special flag
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&q_mux);
        // signal other waiting threads (allows replacing broadcast with signal)
        pthread_cond_signal(&qcond);
        break;
    }   
    dequeue(queue);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&q_mux);
    process(p);
}
```

In this case the "is finished" item is not dequeued so it is seen by all threads; another variation would be to add one "is finished" item for each thread and allow it to be dequeued, such that the queue is fully drained when all threads terminate.

Yet another method is to use an "adding complete" flag with the queue itself and ensure it also signals the mutex. (When a queue is marked as "adding complete" it cannot have new items added.)

```
while (isempty(queue)) {
    if (isaddingcomplete(queue)) {
        // empty and nothing else can be added..
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&q_mux);
        // signal other waiting threads (allows replacing broadcast with signal)
        pthread_cond_signal(&qcond);
        return;
    }
    pthread_cond_wait(&queue_cond,&q_mux);
}
```

There are many ways to skin a gopher.

Comment: I am new to the threads but I thought that the main principle of the thread pool model is that threads after completing the task will just wait and when there is a new packet in the queue it will automatically take it. Or in other words, threads, when they are free, always trying to take a new packet from a queue(and just being stopped when the queue is empty).

Comment: @qwerty Thread execution finishes when they return from their bodies. Nothing standard will "re-run" the threads. While this appears to be an *implementation* of one notion of a thread-pool over specific queue processing, pthreads_create has nothing implicitly to do with a thread pool and does just what was asked: it creates and starts a new thread.

Comment: @qwerty, Re, "I thought that...[the] threads...will just..." A thread that you create will never do _anything_ except execute the code that _you_ provide for it to execute. If you provide code that takes _one_ object from a queue and "processes" it, then that's what the thread will do. That's _all_ the thread will do. If you want the thread to "wait [until] there is a new packet in the queue...," then it's up to you to write the code that waits for and processes additional packets.